# TeXStudio Embedded PDF viewer

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

Is it possible to have TeXStudio to display PDF file side by side with the source code just like TeXMaker? I am asking this since their user interfaces are very similar, hinting that we should have the same functionality in TeXStudio also. At the moment when I press quick build it views the PDF file in a separate window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ACtually TeXStudio is a fork derived from TeXMaker, and for a time it was called TeXMakerX. In my own experience the embedded viewer is the default option. Didn you changed it or customized TeXStudio?

Comment: I have been using TeXStudio mostly with default settings. The launched program is its own PDF viewer but it opens a new window. I want to see the source code and the PDF side by side.

Comment: I preffer to use it in a new window because my screen is small. Well take a look in the menu `Visualize` and select the option `Show embedded PDF small`. This should fix your troubles. Tell if if it works or not.

Comment: The menu Visualize is not available in my edition (2.3) of TeXStudio I presume. How can I change this setting?

Comment: 2.3??? oh boy that's quite old. Hmm well maybe not so much but you should upgrade it. My version is the 2.6.6. I'm no expert TeXStudio user, I have more experience with Texmaker (since version 1.9) but may help to upgrade your version.

Comment: Okay I installed it with the sudo-get command and I would appreciate it if you aid me in upgrading.

Comment: Mmm I see you are using a gnu/linux family SO, actually a debian based one. If you are using ubuntu you only need to download the package according your system (32 or 64 bits) and install the .deb package. Easy.

Comment: I installed it that way but it display two errors upon launch related with loading of dictionaries.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11978/discussion-between-aradnix-and-vesnog)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

2.6.6 is the latest TexStudio Version.  At the top left of an open pdf view, there is an icon that shows a split window.  Click on that and you'll get the side-by-side view you ask for.

Comment: I tried installing it but I ran into additional problems related with dictionaries

Comment: @Vesnog Feel free to ask a follow-up question about that as a new question.

Comment: Is there a way to do that as default?

Comment: @user50358 Yes, see [my anser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362092/123129).

Answer (score 12):

In TexStudio "2.11.2" click on "Tools" > "View" or F7 to enable the pdf side window.

Answer (score 6):

The adjustments suggested in the other answers via the view only affect the current session and are not saved permanently.

You can set the windowed preview as **default** under `options` -> `Configure TeXstudio...`. Goto tab `Build` and change `PDF Viewer` to `Internal PDF Viewer (Windowed)`.

If you want the preview in the same window select `Internal PDF Viewer (Embedded)`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In 2.7.0, click on "View" and the click on "Show embedded PDF small".

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

Tools --> View or press <kbd>F7</kbd> it will display automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on source code area then click on "go to pdf". Now Embedded PDF viewer appears.
texstudio 2.12.16